# Register Yeoman Generator non-cli

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I want to run a Yeoman generator without the cli (`yo`).  I see the instructions [in the Yeoman documentation](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/wiki/Using-yeoman-in-non-cli-environment) about how to run a generator without the CLI environment.

If I run `yo mygenerator:mysubgenerator` it works (it's installed globally), but using `env.run('mygenerator:mysubgenerator')` from node does not work.  It says that the generator is not installed.

I think this has to do with the `//register/lookup generators` step in the documentation above, but they don't include how to do this at all.  How can I register my globally-installed generator?

Answer (score 0):

There's a complete documentation here: http://yeoman.io/authoring/integrating-yeoman.html

The basic idea is you need to lookup installed generators before you can run them:

```
env.lookup(function () {
  env.run('angular');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try on this way:

```
env.register(require.resolve('generator-mygenerator'), 'mygenerator:mysubgenerator');
```